# Rails 4: conditional display not working inside view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement, view

In my Rails 4 app, there is a Post model, with both a `:copy` and a `:short_copy` attribute.

In the Posts#Show view, I want to display the `:short_copy` if it was defined by the user, and the `:copy` otherwise.

So, I implemented the following code:

```
<% if @post.short_copy %>
  <%= @post.short_copy %>
<% else %>
  <%= @post.copy %>
<% end %>
```

Problem: when the `:short_copy` is defined, it does show up, however, when it is not defined (and a `:copy` *is* defined), the `:copy` does not show up.

Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: Is it possible that @post.short_copy is equal to an empty string?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, you are correct. And then, if `@post.short_copy` it is not nil, so we display it, and nothing appears. So, I need to test it doing something like `unless @post.short_copy.nil? || @post.short_copy.empty?` for instance?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I would do `@post.short_copy.nil?`, but then you'll need to make sure that your user input saves correctly or is `nil`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String#blank?` to check for a value - an empty string is still `true`

```
<% if !@post.short_copy.blank? %>
  <%= @post.short_copy %>
<% else %>
  <%= @post.copy %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `@post.short_copy.present?` will also work, if you prefer to not use a `!` in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that there is nothing wrong with your code in essence, but you may be mislead by the value of @post.short_copy. Unless it is `nil` or `false` the `<% if @post.short_copy %>` will be run. I would imagine that `@post.short_copy = ''`, and is therefore displaying nothing in the view.

Answer (score 1):

I just run this snippet:

```
2.1.1 :002 > if("")
2.1.1 :003?>   printf "yes"
2.1.1 :004?>   else
2.1.1 :005 >     printf "no"
2.1.1 :006?>   end
(irb):6: warning: string literal in condition
yes => nil
```

So - if short_copy is empty string, it will evaluate to true. So try this:

```
2.1.1 :020 > unless("".empty?)
2.1.1 :021?>   printf "yes"
2.1.1 :022?>   else
2.1.1 :023 >     printf "no"
2.1.1 :024?>   end
no => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use `string.blank?` to check if nil or empty string. Use `array.empty?` if field is array. So in your case, you can use blank?

`<% unless @post.short_copy.blank? %>
      <%= @post.short_copy %>
    <% else %>
      <%= @post.copy %>
    <% end %>`